# Where does the term 'Castled' come from?

Tags: cricket, terminology

So you often hear when a bowler bowls a batsman that "he has castled him". Where does this term originate from and how has it come to be used in Cricket?

I found an example in commentary.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIV5QPW7CCU&t=34s

Comment: Just a guess, but the term is commonly used in Chess - though I see no direct logical meaning.

Comment: The only possible link I can think of is that the wickets are the batsmans castle and the bowler by beating the batsman and striking the wickets has toppled the batsmans castle, but it's just a thought :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Castle*[1] is used as a term that denotes the wicket that the batsman *guards*. Hence, comes the verb *castled* which refers to breaching the batsman's fort and disturbing his wickets.

Origin of the word castle comes from the Latin word *castrum*, which means fort. I do not know the details of the first recorded usage of castle in a cricketing context.

[1] - http://www.dictionarycentral.com/definition/castle.html